# Update/Edit data using repository MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository, repository-pattern

I've previously learned how to insert/add data using a repository and I tried to applied that to updating/editing. But when I run the program, it doesn't seem to find the id and proceeds to make a new entry.

Controller:

```
 //EDIT
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Driver editDriver = db.Drivers.Find(id);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(DriverViewModel DVM)
    {
        var repo = new ManagementRepository();
        var driver = new Driver();         

        driver.DriverLastName = DVM.DriverLastName;
        driver.DriverFirstName = DVM.DriverFirstName;
        driver.DriverLicense = DVM.DriverLicense;
        driver.LicenseExpiry = DVM.LicenseExpiry;
        driver.MobileNumber = DVM.MobileNumber;
        driver.BusinessUnit = DVM.BusinessUnit;

        repo.UpdateDriver(driver);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public void UpdateDriver(Driver updateDriver)
    {
        using (var db = new VehicleReservationEntities())
        {
            var existingDriver = (from data in db.Drivers
                                  where data.DriverID == updateDriver.DriverID
                                  select data).FirstOrDefault();

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using EntityFramework here, the reason why your repository looses track of the entity you're trying to update is because you're using a different DbContext instance.

A DbContext instance is "aware" of the objects that get pulled from it, added to it, etc. but what you're doing is grabbing a object from one DbContext (which is tracking it) and sending it to another DbContext (which is not tracking it, hence why it thinks it's a new object and tries to add it).

Also I would recommend (since you're using Asp.Net) using Dependency injection into your controllers to avoid this exact problem.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Just to summarize all of this and give a short answer, use a DbContext instance when selecting the object, update it with the new values you want, and use the same DbContext to update the entity, after which save changes. This will update the entity you recovered from the database instead of trying to add a new one.